# Objective c, reposition a view above the keyboard in one single animation

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextview, inputaccessoryview

I have a custom view at the bottom of my screen, i want to reposition it above the keyboard when it opens up.

I know i can register for the '**KeyboardWasShown**' notification and then reposition the view or as the apple documentation suggests to use a **scrollview** with **scrollRectToVisible**, but the problem i have with both options is that it is not done as part of the keyboard animation.
I can see the keyboard appear and only a second later the view is repositioned or scrolled in to view.

Another option i tried was to set this view as InputAccessory for the textView im editing, This works very well but my view will not be visible once the keyboard is closed, and i need it to be available all the time.

I suppose i can create two instances of this view and have one as inputAccessory and the other just sitting in the bottom, but i really dont like this solution and these views have a state that will have to be synced between the two instances

Can anyone suggest an alternative solution ?

Comment: You want to sync the keyboard show/hide animation and your view's animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification.

Add observer first.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardFrameChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

The selector will be...

```
- (void)keyboardFrameChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect begin        = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect end          = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat keyboardSize= begin.size.height;
    BOOL isShowing      = begin.origin.y > end.origin.y;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // do view animation here.

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The animation of your view and the keyboard will be sync.

Comment: Thanks, this works great,
I will point out that according to apple documentation the use of: , beginAnimations, setAnimationDuration, setAnimationCurve, setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState is discoraged in ios 4 and higher
add you should use animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: instead of all of them